# How to restrict permissions for administering Taxonomy?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I would like a user role to be able to add/edit terms for a specific vocabulary, but not all vocabularies.

In the permission settings for taxonomy, it seems that I need to give the role permission to 'Administer vocabularies and terms'. But then they can edit *all* vocabularies; the edit/delete permissions for each vocabulary don't have any effect?

I've seen various taxonomy access modules, but they seem to restrict the use of terms on nodes etc. My situation is more simple; a specific role just needs to be able to add additional terms to a vocabulary.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I just posted a similar question. Any light in this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23018/how-to-grant-a-role-permission-to-edit-terms-in-a-specific-vocabulary

Answer (score 9):

For D7 there is a [taxonomy access fix](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix) module. It makes it possible to manage access permissions to individual vocabularies.

Comment: Great find; here's the link http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix

Comment: I have given add terms permission for a role but it show access denied.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some specific taxonomy access modules that may help you like [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) or [TAC lite](http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite).

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can tell, these modules are for controlling access to content using taxonomy. I need to control admin of a specific vocabulary; ie. allow a role to add terms to it.