# How to grant a role permission to edit terms in a specific vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there a way/module to grant a role permission to list and edit terms in a specific vocabulary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only module I can think of is the [Taxonomy access fix](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix) module, which has only a version for Drupal 7.

> This module
>
> - adds 1 permission per vocabulary: "add terms in X"
> - changes the way vocabulary specific permissions are handled
> - changes the Taxonomy admin pages' access checks
> - alters the vocabularies overview table to show only what you have access to edit or delete
>
> The module does what native Taxonomy lacks: more specific Taxonomy permissions (and checking them correctly).

Comment: it currently has a d8 version, (this is while the issue is being fixed in d8 core https://www.drupal.org/node/1848686)

Comment: I have given add terms permission for a role but it show access denied page.

Answer (score 2):

Both answers didn't work for me. "Taxonomy access fix" didn't work at all and the drupal permissions didn't work as expected. The only thing which is still having a chance to work is http://drupal.org/project/vppr - you may download a D7 version on the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Vocabulary Permissions per Role https://drupal.org/project/vppr works. It adds these permissions so you can give access to users per Vocabulary:
https://drupal.org/project/vppr

They can not change or delete the vocabulary itself, which is important. So they can not really administer the vocabulary but its terms.